# Problems using only fileInput on Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm inserting two codes: the first code works very well, but my database is mentioned in the code. However, I have this database in Excel and I'm trying to use it only by `fileInput` (second code). Unfortunately it's not working, the table that was supposed to be shown isn't working. Could you help me solve this problem?? Thank you very much!

To make it easier, I'm providing the excel database I'm using. https://syr.us/rVo

**First code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(readxl)
library(DT)
 
  
function.test<-function(){
    
    Test <- structure(list(date2 = structure(c(18808, 18808, 18809, 18810
    ), class = "Date"), Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"), 
    coef = c(4, 1, 6, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

    return(Test)

  }
  

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 uiOutput('fileInput'),
                                 uiOutput('daterange')
                               
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                                 dataTableOutput('table')

                               )
                             ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  

  data <- reactive(function.test())
  

  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   min = min(data()$date2),
                   max = max(data()$date2))
  })
  
  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    showModal(modalDialog("Wait", footer=NULL))
    on.exit(removeModal())
    All<- subset(data(), date2 %in% days)
    All<-All%>% mutate(TOTAL = rowSums(across(3:last_col()), na.rm = TRUE))
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
   datatable(data_subset(),options = list( columnDefs = list(
          list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all")),
        paging = TRUE,  searching = FALSE,pageLength = 10,dom = 'tip',  scrollx=TRUE),    rownames = FALSE) %>%
      formatRound(c(3:4), digits=0)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Second code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(readxl)
library(DT)
 
  
function.test<-function(){
    
    return(Test)

  }
  

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 uiOutput('fileInput'),
                                 uiOutput('daterange')
                               
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                                 dataTableOutput('table')

                               )
                             ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(function.test())
  
  data <- eventReactive(input$file, {
    if (is.null(input$file)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    else {
      df <- read_excel(input$file$datapath)
      return(df)
    }
 })
  
  output$fileInput <- renderUI({
    fileInput("file",h4("Import file"),
             multiple = T,accept = ".xlsx",
              placeholder = "No file selected")
  })
  

  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   min = min(data()$date2),
                   max = max(data()$date2))
  })
  
  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    showModal(modalDialog("Wait", footer=NULL))
    on.exit(removeModal())
    All<- subset(data(), date2 %in% days)
    All<-All%>% mutate(TOTAL = rowSums(across(3:last_col()), na.rm = TRUE))
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
   datatable(data_subset(),options = list( columnDefs = list(
          list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all")),
        paging = TRUE,  searching = FALSE,pageLength = 10,dom = 'tip',  scrollx=TRUE),    rownames = FALSE) %>%
      formatRound(c(3:4), digits=0)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(writexl)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(readxl)

return_coef <- function(df1, dmda, CategoryChosse) {
  
  x<-df1 %>% dplyr::select(starts_with("DR0"))
  
  x <- cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
  PV <- dplyr::select(x, date2,Week, Category, DR1, ends_with("PV"))
  
  med<-PV %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median))
  
  SPV<-df1%>%
    inner_join(med, by = c('Category', 'Week')) %>%
    mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                    get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                  .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
    dplyr::select(date1:Category, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())
  
  SPV<-data.frame(SPV)
  
  mat1 <- df1 %>%
    dplyr::filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    dplyr::select(starts_with("DR0")) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
    arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
    mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
    dplyr::filter(cs == 0) %>%
    pull(name)
  
  (dropnames <- paste0(mat1,"_",mat1, "_PV"))
  
  SPV <- SPV %>%
    dplyr::filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    dplyr::select(-any_of(dropnames))
  
  if(length(grep("DR0", names(SPV))) == 0) {
    SPV[head(mat1,10)] <- NA_real_
  }
  
  datas <-SPV %>%
    dplyr::filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
    group_by(Category) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(across(starts_with("DR0"), sum)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols= -Category, names_pattern = "DR0(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = readr::parse_number(name))
  colnames(datas)[-1]<-c("Days","Numbers")
  
  
  datas <- datas %>% 
    group_by(Category) %>% 
    slice((as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [
      df1$Category == first(Category)])):max(Days)+1) %>%
    ungroup
  
  m<-df1 %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(across(starts_with("DR1"), mean))
  
  m<-subset(m, Week == df1$Week[match(ymd(dmda), ymd(df1$date2))] & Category == CategoryChosse)$DR1
  
  
  if (nrow(datas)<=2){
    return (as.numeric(m))
  }
  
  else if(any(table(datas$Numbers) >= 3) & length(unique(datas$Numbers)) == 1){
    yz <- unique(datas$Numbers)
    return(as.numeric(yz))
    
  }
  
  else{
    mod <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0),data = datas, algorithm = "port")
    return(as.numeric(coef(mod)[2]))
  }
  
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 uiOutput('fileInput'),
                                 uiOutput('daterange')
                                 
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                                 dataTableOutput('table')
                               )
                             ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  output$fileInput <- renderUI({
    fileInput("file",h4("Import file"), multiple = T, accept = ".xlsx")
  })
  
  data <- eventReactive(input$file, {
    if (is.null(input$file)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    else {
      df3 <- read_excel(input$file$datapath)
      validate(need(all(c('date1', 'date2') %in% colnames(df3)), "Incorrect file"))
      df4 <- df3 %>% mutate_if(~inherits(., what = "POSIXct"), as.Date) # Change POSIXct variables to Date class
      return(df4)
    }
  })
  
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   min = min(data()$date2),
                   max = max(data()$date2))
  })
  
  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1, data())
    req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    df1 <- subset(data(), as.Date(date2) %in% days)
    df2 <- df1 %>% dplyr::select(date2,Category)
    Test <- cbind(df2, coef = apply(df2, 1, function(x) {return_coef(df1,x[1],x[2])}))
    Test
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data_subset()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks YBS, but that's another code. This one is using function and the database is being mentioned in the code. I would just like by `fileInput`, do you know how to adjust this? It may even be this code that you inserted there, but I didn't want to mention the database, because it will only be for `fileInput`. In the example above I didn't insert the function because I wanted to reduce code to be as clear as possible.

Comment: YBS, thanks, I will check this code. YBS, we can talk by email or chat?

Comment: Thanks YBS, I'll do it, I think it's easier to explain. I already got your contact and I will send you an email soon. Thank you very much! =)

Comment: I sent you an email to you, please, when you can, check only if you received it. Thanks YBS!

Comment: Thanksss YBS =)

Comment: Please try the updated code.

Comment: Thanks YBS, that's what I wanted. I replied in the email too.

Comment: YBS,  this question is almost the same as the one I sent you in the email. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69669499/how-to-use-two-sheet-of-a-spreadsheet-in-shiny-code